# How to pass array from assembly to a C function

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, x86, nasm

I wanna pass an array defined in assembly code to a C function, but i'm getting a segment violation error when i try to access that array in my C code. Here is the assembly code (i'm using nasm):

```
%include "io.inc"
extern minimo ;My C function
extern printf

section .data
   array db 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ;My array
   alen db 5               ;My array length
   fmt db "%d", 10, 0      ;Format for the printf function

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
   xor eax, eax

   mov ebx, [alen]
   mov ecx, [array]
   
   push ebx
   push ecx
   call minimo
   add esp, 8

   push eax
   push fmt
   call printf
   add esp, 8
   
   mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 80h
```

And here is my C code:

```
int minimo(int *array, int size){
   int ret = array[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
      if(array[i] < ret){
         ret = array[i];
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: `mov ecx, [array]` moves the first 4 bytes of `array` into ECX. If you want to put the address in ECX it would be `mov ecx, array`. You are also moving the 4 bytes starting from `alen` into EBX. If you mean to to do that make `alen` a `dd` and not a `db`

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Another weird thing is you made `array` an array of bytes (using `db`) but your function takes an array of ints. If you want an array of ints you will have to change `array` to be `dd` instead of `db`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch you are right, "mov ecx, array" solved my issue, like PIRIQITI pointed out as well. And yes, i changed it to dd instead of db as you suggested because i was not getting correct output (it was throwing weird numbers) but with this correction now i see the numbers i placed in the output. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mov ecx, [array] **moves the value sitting on the location "array" points to, so you need to move an address** `mov ecx, array` **will do**